# Uninstaller not working due to runtime exceptions

Tags: uninstallation, install4j

We are developing GUI/CLI based Installer for CentOS 7 and observe issue on few machines that after installation completion if we try to run Uninstaller it is giving error prompt with The uninstaller cannot instantiated.

When we investigated further we are getting this exception in log files.

```
[ERROR] Error setting the look and feel
[ERROR] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.runtime.flatlaf.FlatLafLookAndFeelHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.runtime.flatlaf.FlatLafLookAndFeelHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forNameImpl(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:410)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.LookAndFeelHelper.instantiateLookAndFeelHandler(LookAndFeelHelper.java:128)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.LookAndFeelHelper.createLookAndFeelHandler(LookAndFeelHelper.java:114)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.LookAndFeelHelper.setLookAndFeelUnconditional(LookAndFeelHelper.java:66)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.LookAndFeelHelper.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeelHelper.java:55)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.showMessage(GUIHelper.java:228)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.showMessage(GUIHelper.java:218)
    at com.install4j.api.Util$2.run(Util.java:345)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.actions.RunAction.execute(RunAction.java:11)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionDirect(HelperCommunication.java:292)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeActionInt(HelperCommunication.java:267)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.comm.HelperCommunication.executeAction(HelperCommunication.java:244)
    at com.install4j.api.Util.showMessage(Util.java:342)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.config.InstallerConfig.setCurrentApplicationId(InstallerConfig.java:65)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.runInProcess(Uninstaller.java:38)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Uninstaller.main(Uninstaller.java:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:66)
    at install4j.Uninstaller2350755325.main(Unknown Source)
```

Please comment on this behavior.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the installation is damaged and some files are missing.

Comment: But how come it is damaged when we are trying to uninstall immediately after fresh installation?

Comment: Maybe the installation fails with a fatal error and is inconsistent?

Comment: How can I check that means any way to find the ROOT cause

Comment: The file .install4j/installation.log in the installation directory should give some clues